# Simple song list, using array lists and objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this exercise that i need to finish, I'm supposed to make a simple song player (doesn't actually play songs) but its supposed to ask for the user for the song name, time, store it into an array, and stop until the user enters an empty spot, its then supposed to swap the order, and "play" the songs (basically list the song name and just write "na na na na na" under it, this is what I have so far.

### `Song` class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Song {

    // ---------- Instance Variables -------------------------------------- //
    private String title;
    private int totalSeconds;
    private String time;

    // ---------- Constructors -------------------------------------------- //
    /**
     * Create a song from its title and running time
     *
     * @param t the title of the song
     * @param l song's run time (<i>mm</i>:<i>ss</i> -- for example: "3:07")
     */
    public Song(String t, String l) {
        java.util.Scanner reader = new Scanner(l);
        reader.useDelimiter(":");
        int mins = reader.nextInt();
        int secs = reader.nextInt();

        setFields(t, mins, secs);
    }

    // ---------- Public Methods ------------------------------------------ //
    /**
     * The length of this Song, in seconds.
     *
     * @return the running time of the song (in seconds)
     */
    public int getLengthInSeconds() {
        return totalSeconds;
    }

    /** 
     * "Play" the song 
     */
    public void play() {
        System.out.print("\nNow Playing: " + title);
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSeconds; i++) {
            if (i % 25 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print("na ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int)(100 * Math.random()));
            }
            catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * Return a string representation of the song, including its title and run
     * time.
     *
     * @return a String for the song: "<i>title</i> (<i>run-time</i>)"
     */
    public String toString() {
        return title + " (" + time + ")";
    }

    // ---------- Private Methods ----------------------------------------- //
    /**
     * Set the all the instance variables in this object.
     * Called by the constructor.
     *
     * @param t title of song
     * @param minutes the running time (minutes part -- the 3 of 3:07)
     * @param seconds the running time's excess seconds (the 7 of 3:07)
     */
    private void setFields(String t, int minutes, int seconds) {
        title = t;
        totalSeconds = 60 * minutes + seconds;
        time = minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0": "") + seconds;
    }

}
```

### `SongPlayer` class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SongPlayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System. in );
        int numOfSongs;

        System.out.println("This Player can hold up to 20 songs, and plays them in a random order.");
        System.out.println("Enter the song titles and lengths below. Leave the title blank to end early.");

        System.out.println("How many songs?");
        numOfSongs = scnr.nextInt();
        String songNames[] = new String[numOfSongs];
        int songLength[] = new int[numOfSongs];

        for (int i = 0; i < songNames.length; i++) {
            Scanner scnr2 = new Scanner(System. in );
            System.out.print("Enter song title: ");
            songNames[i] = scnr2.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter song Length eg (3:07) : ");
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System. in );
            reader.useDelimiter(":");
            int mins = reader.nextInt();
            int secs = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The song " + songNames[i] + "(" + mins + ":" + secs + ") has been added.");

        }

    }

}
```

I'm supposed to use the `Song` class to get the time and all that, but I really don't know how I should go about this.

The output should look something like this.

```
Enter song name : First song
Enter song length: 3:07
Song First song (3:07) has been added.
```

This it does it for the rest of the songs.

Then it swaps the order in the array.

And just play like this:

```
PLaying First Song:
Na na na na na na na na na na na na na na.....
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: well first of all it doesnt print out the part where it would say Song was added, i dont know why, and i dont know how to use the other class to implement it in the SongPlayer class

Comment: Did you debug to see why it doesn't print anything out?

Comment: never really used it no

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and give it a go. Learning to debug will save you hours in the long run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an exercise you have to do yourself, I will not give the solution (code). Instead, I will give you few tips. You can try them yourself.

Since this is a simple program, use `Song` class as a simple data structure. (e.g. Do not use `Scanner` inside `Song`.) Something like this:

```
public class Song {
    private String title;
    private String time;
}
```

Use only one `Scanner` object. You can reuse it to get multiple inputs from user.

You can use `java.util.Collections.shuffle(java.util.List)` API to shuffle the songs.

Since above `shuffle()` method takes in a `List` as its parameter, better to collect user inputted songs to a `List` object (may be an `ArrayList`).

If you want the user input to end early, then after getting song title from user using `songNames[i] = scnr2.nextLine();`, you need to check whether it is empty and break the loop like:

```
if (songNames[i].isEmpty()) {
    break;
}
```

Since the duration of songs are used for printing, consider inputting then as `String`s. That will make the program simpler.

After getting all the user input songs, you need to have another `for` loop to print those songs.